# why cant I change the backround with bootstrap?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>
    <div style="background-color:grey">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
           <h1>hello</h1>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hey there!, first post here, can anybody tell me why this won't work? i've simplified my code to the maximum. The thing is that it will work if i make my browser window smaller than 1200px.

Comment: This is a good first post, the minimal example really helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your page is that you did not put in place all the structure required by bootstrap's grid support: columns should be in rows, rows should be in containers, see the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for details.

The following modification of your code works as intended:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/c\
ss/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div style="background-color:grey" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1>hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(Technically the problem occurs because the "col-lg-12" class makes the div containing the "hello" a float, so it is no longer contained in the div with the grey background, and then the grey div has height 0, so isn't visible.)

Answer (score 0):

Add the position or height attribute to the div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color:grey;position:absolute">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
       <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```